# how to duplicate specific character in a file using batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have this issue -

I'm getting a property from a property file, and I set it as a parameter until that point all good.

After that, I'm trying to use this parameter in Jenkins but problem is that the `\` character is disappearing, so:

```
EncdbaPassword=QCC\:daD1SWita/YD2EfnWC4cXg\=\=
```

will look like:

```
EncdbaPassword=QCC:daD1SWita/YD2EfnWC4cXg==
```

What I need is to duplicate the `\` character and then Jenkins will read this parameter properly.

```
EncdbaPassword=QCC\\:daD1SWita/YD2EfnWC4cXg\\=\\=
```

How do I duplicate the `\` character using a batch file?
So that after every time this character is shown it will add another one after it?

*note- the parameter string is not always the same and is changing from time to time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply like this using batch replacement:

```
set EncdbaPassword=%EncdbaPassword:\=\\%
```